# How to find parent-child relationships between geometric features? Or is there another way of dealing with GIS data?

Tags: spatial-database, spatial-relationship

I have bunch of shapefiles from [OpenStreetsMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org). A simple understanding of human is that we know which feature is inside which feature. And it's mathematically constrained. In other words, it's impossible for a given tree to be in two cities. Thus if we might define *inclusion* attribute for geometric and geographical features.

I need to make my data more meaningful by creating relationships between features. Like for example I need to store that this city belongs to this state, or this college is in this city, and so on and so forth.

This seems to be a very natural requirement, thus I searched and to my surprise I found not much about how it works and how to achieve it. For example, [Managing MySQL spatial polygons in parent child style?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109742) is unanswered 2 years later with no upvotes.

Maybe I'm not thinking **GIS**ly and I need to change my understanding.

Is it OK to think hierarchically in GIS?

If so, how to related unrelated data?

If not, what other approaches do we use?

Answer (score 3):

The relationships that you mentioned are called **topological** relationships (relationships that do not depend on the shape of the features) in GIS. The majority of the situations can be represented based on two relationships (intersect or disjoint) for their interiors, their boundaries and their exteriors. Most GIS can compute the topological relationships on the fly (using spatial queries) but do not store them in the attribute table of their database. It is however possible to add attributes from one feature ot another according to topological relationships using **spatial join** tools (usually for the "intersect" relationship).

So, to try and answer your question, you will often think "topologically" in GIS, but you will not store this information because there are too many possible relationships (especially if you add some tolerance value, e.g. the tree is inside a 100m buffer around the city boundaries) and the relationships are sometimes more complex than a parent-child relationship (e.g. different rivers could cross several states). The only reason for storing topological relationship in an attribute table is this could be the optimisation of a frequent request. Sometimes, some relationships are explicitly stored in the database (e.g. ArcInfo coverage) but this was for neighbors.